# How to save different file from one file using value in specific column using bash

Tags: awk, match, multiple-columns, newline

i want to save line using value from column `$1` and save the line in one file using value from `$1`, if it has different value save it into another new file

```
112 14.7 114.98 -0.92 -0.12
112 14.8 114.02 -0.78  0.76
112 14.1 114.99 -0.98 -0.11
113 12.5 111.77  1.87 -1.88
113 12.6 111.89 -0.98 -1.65  
115 15.7 110.8   2.06  0.72
118 11.9 111.01 -1.04  0.98
```

what i want is

```
file1=p004112.txt
112 14.7 114.98 -0.92 -0.12
112 14.8 114.02 -0.78  0.76
112 14.1 114.99 -0.98 -0.11

file2=p004113.txt
113 12.5 111.77  1.87 -1.88
113 12.6 111.89 -0.98 -1.65 

file3=p004115.txt
115 15.7 110.8   2.06  0.72

file4=p004118.txt
118 11.9 111.01 -1.04  0.98
```

the file that has to change like that has namefile `p004.txt p005.txt`
i have tried like this
`` for i in `ls p????.txt|sed "s/.txt//g"`;do awk '{file=${i}$1".txt" print >> file}' ${i}.txt;done ``
but it doesn't work :( anyone has the solution from this problem?
Thank you

Comment: i have tried ``for i in `ls p????_s.txt | sed "s/.txt//g"`; do paste ${i}.txt | awk 'prev!=$1{close(outputFile);outputFile=(${i}"_"$1".txt")} {print > (outputFile);prev=$1}';done`` but it's still error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Though your samples are shown as sorted 1st column but I have still used `sort` to sort the file with 1st column, in case your whole file is sorted with 1st column then remove sort command from following and paste `Input_file` at the end of `awk` program.

```
sort -k1 Input_file | awk 'prev!=$1{close(outputFile);outputFile=("p004"$1".txt")} {print > (outputFile);prev=$1}'
```

OR a non-oneliner form of above solution:

```
sort -k1 Input_file | 
awk '
  prev!=$1{
    close(outputFile)
    outputFile=("p004"$1".txt")
  }
  {       
    print > (outputFile)
    prev=$1
  }
'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be: Firstly sorting the Input_file with 1st column and sending its output as an Input to `awk` command. Then in `awk` program: Setting outputFile name to p004 with 1st column name appended with .txt as per need by OP and closing the output file in backend to avoid "too many opened files" error, this is done each time 1st column is changing(not equal to its previous line's value). Then printing each line into output file and setting prev value to 1st column value in each line.

Comment: @RETNO EKA YUNI P, please do let me know on which file you are running it.

Comment: i will run it on all file, like file `p004.txt, p005.txt and other file`. but, if i run with your script i have to run one by one. I have tried using `for` but it doesn't work